# PHP - values not saved in array

Tags: php, arrays

Apologies, but couldn't find an answer to this already...

I have some PHP code that hits an error, which I echo and save to an array:

```
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $errors[] = "File is not an image";
```

The array is defined earlier:

```
    $errors = array();
```

When I debug my web page, I can see the echo (so I know it's hitting that error) but the array is empty...screenshot below:

[screenshot of web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZbFX.png)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or how to debug further?

Thanks!

Simon

EDIT: I noticed the array was declared twice. Removed that, no change.

Full code below

```
<?php
class BanditquotecustomformModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

  public function initContent()
  {
    $varCountry = '';
    $varRemarks = '';
    $varContactEmail = '';
    $varCustomerName = '';
    $varPhone = '';
    $varUrgency = '';
    $sql = ''; 
    $user_id ='';
    /* For when I get this working!
    $id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
    $category = Category::searchByName($id_lang,"personalised",true);*/


    /*parent::initContent();*/
    if ($this->context->customer->isLogged())
    {
      $this->setTemplate('customform.tpl');
      $custfirstname = $this->context->customer->firstname;
      $custlastname = $this->context->customer->lastname;
      $custemail = $this->context->customer->email;
      $this->context->smarty->assign('firstname', $custfirstname);
      $this->context->smarty->assign('lastname', $custlastname);
      $this->context->smarty->assign('customer_email', $custemail);

      parent::initContent();
    }
    else
    {
          Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication&back='.urlencode($this->context->link->getModuleLink('banditquote', 'customform')));
    }

  }

  /* adds a new product for every quote */
  private function addProduct($LastId)
  {
    $reference = 'CUST'.$LastId;  
        $name = $reference;
    $product = new Product();
        $languages=Language::getLanguages();
        foreach($languages as $lang){
          $product->name[$lang['id_lang']]=$name;
          $product->link_rewrite[$lang['id_lang']]=$name;
          $product->description[$lang['id_lang']]=$name;
        }   
        $product->reference=$reference;
    $product->active='1';
    $product->available_for_order='1';
        $product->is_virtual='1';
    /* add product to category */
        $product->id_category='2';
        $product->id_category_default='2';
    try{
          $product->save();
        } catch (PrestaShopException $e){
          echo $e->displayMessage();
        }
        $product->addToCategories(array(2));
        $product->save();

        $prod_shopupdate = Db::getInstance()->Execute('
                    UPDATE `'.pSQL(_DB_PREFIX_).'product_shop`
                    SET `active` = "1",`available_for_order` = "1"
                    WHERE `id_product` = "'.((int)$product->id).'"');


    return $product->id;
  }

  /* checking attachment */
  private function checkImage()
  {
    $target_dir = '_THEME_PROD_PIC_DIR_';
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 0;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $errors[] = $this->module->l('File is an image', 'customform');
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image";
        $errors[] = "File is not an image";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

     // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
      $errors[] = $this->module->l('Sorry, file already exists', 'customform');
      $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
      $errors[] = $this->module->l('Sorry, your file is too large', 'customform');
      $uploadOk = 0;
    }

   // Allow certain file formats
   if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
   && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
     $errors[] = $this->module->l('Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed', 'customform');
     $uploadOk = 0;
   }

   // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error 
   if ($uploadOk == 0) {
     $errors[] = $this->module->l('Sorry, your file was not uploaded', 'customform');
     // if everything is ok, try to upload file
   }
   else {
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
     }
     else {
        $errors[] = $this->module->l('Sorry, there was an error uploading your file', 'customform');
     }
   }

   return $uploadOk;
  }

  public function postProcess()
  {
      if (Tools::isSubmit('submit'))
      {

          $errors = array();
          $failed = false;
          $varUserId = (int)$this->context->customer->id;
          $varRemarks = Tools::getValue('formRemarks');
          $newRemarks = str_replace("'","''", $varRemarks);
          $varCountry = Tools::getValue('formCountry');
          $varContactEmail = Tools::getValue('formContactEmail');
      $varCustomerName = Tools::getValue('formCustomerName');
      $varPhone = Tools::getValue('formPhone');
      $varUrgency = Tools::getValue('formUrgency');
      if (empty($varRemarks))
      {
        $errors[] = $this->module->l('The message cannot be blank.', 'customform');
        //d($errors);
      }
      else
      {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `ps_quotes` (`quote_destin`,`quote_remarks`,`quote_email`,`quote_submitter_name`,`quote_phone`,`quote_urg`,`quote_user_id`)
                    VALUES('{$varCountry}','{$newRemarks}','{$varContactEmail}','{$varCustomerName}','{$varPhone}','{$varUrgency}','{$varUserId}');";

            if (!Db::getInstance()->execute($sql))
            {
              die('Error creating Custom Order - Please contact admin@banditbirds.co.uk');
            }
            $quoteid = Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID();
            $prod_id = $this->addProduct(Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID());
            if ($prod_id == null )
            {
              die('Error creating Custom Product for Custom Order - Please contact admin@banditbirds.co.uk');
            }
            $updatesql = "UPDATE `ps_quotes` SET `quote_product_link` = $prod_id WHERE `quote_id` = $quoteid;";
            Db::getInstance()->execute($updatesql);


            //Check the uploaded attachment - if there
            if ( $this->checkImage() )
            {

            // add ps_attachment
            // link ps_attachment to product with ps_product_attachment


            }
            else
            {
              $this->context->smarty->assign('errors', $errors);
              $failed = true;
              d($errors);
            }

            //Mailing
            $confirmation1 = '';
            $template = 'banditquote';
            $template_owner = 'banditquote_owner';
        $template_vars = array(
            '{banditquote_contactaddress}' => '',
            '{banditquote_contacttown}' => '',
            '{shop_url}' => Tools::getShopDomain(true),
                                        /* in case we need to check ssl $this->ssl_enable ? Tools::getShopDomainSsl(true) : Tools::getShopDomain(true);*/
            '{remarks}' => $varRemarks,
            '{shipping_destination}' => $varCountry,
            '{phone}' => $varPhone,
            '{name_cust}' => $varCustomerName,
            '{shipping_quantity}' => '',
            '{paypal}' => '',
            '{first_order}' => '',
            '{urgency}' => $varUrgency,
            '{language}' => (int)$this->context->language->id,
            '{webmaster}' => 'admin@banditbirds.co.uk',
            '{email}' => $varContactEmail,
            '{shop_name}' => Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME'),
            '{owner_email}' => Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL'));


        $language = (int)$this->context->language->id;
        $maildir = '/home/banditbi/public_html/modules/banditquote/mails/1.5/';

        if ((Mail::Send($language, $template, Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME'), $template_vars, $varContactEmail, null, null, null, null, null, $maildir,false,null)) &&
                (Mail::Send($language, $template_owner, Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME'), $template_vars, 'admin@banditbirds.co.uk', null, null, null, null, null, $maildir,false,null)))
        $this->context->smarty->assign('confirmation1', 1);
        else
        {
        if (is_null($confirmation1))
        {
          $this->_html .= '<div style="background:#F00; padding:5px; border:thin; border-color:#030; text-align:center"><A HREF="javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)">'.$this->l('CAPTCHA Error, please go back and try once more.').'</A></div><br />';
          return $this->_html;
        } 
        }

          if( !$failed )
          {
            Tools::redirect('index.php');
          }
        }

       $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'id_customer' => (int)$this->context->customer->id,
            'errors' => $errors,
            'form_link' => $errors,
           ));

       $this->setTemplate('customform.tpl');
      }
  }


}
?>
```

Comment: Which version of php you use??

Comment: Are you mistakenly redefining the array at the end too somewhere?

Comment: lets see all the code, need more context!

Comment: Your code display the array values. Please update full code.

Comment: Need a lot more context than what has been provided. Also, as mentioned in my comment to the answer below, you don't need to define $errors ahead of time.

Comment: @CasparWylie have added code

Comment: @HankyPanky yes I was redefining the array as well as earlier, i've removed that now. No change. Thanks

Comment: In which context you see the array empty? During debug session? Or with a var_dump/print_r somewhere?

Comment: @Mariella I'm using the d($errors) which you can see the output in my screenshot. I'm also outputting in the html:
         `<div class="alert alert-danger"></div>`
         `{foreach $errors as $item}<li>{$item}<li>`
         `{/foreach}`
Have also tried: {$errors|@print_r}
Which outputs: Array ( ) 1

Comment: I think it's a variable scope problem. $errors variable has local scope. The $errors variable of method postProcess is not the same of the one in checkImage method. Consider using a class property. Declare it with "private $errors = array();" just at the beginning of your class and use $this->errors instead of $errors in your methods.

Comment: @Mariella Thank you!!! That solved it. Had to be public not private though

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are defining the array before attempting to store values into it.

```
$errors = array();

$errors[] = 'File is not an image';
```

Do not try to redefine the array after you add items to this array. Otherwise, you will reset the array effectively removing any items previously added.

Comment: There is no need, or reason, to define $errors before adding values to it.

Comment: There also isn't any harm in doing so.  If you read the initial question, they are defining it as an array in their question. Which is why it was included as being defined in my response.

Comment: Didn't say there was. Just trying to make a point that if you are collecting things like errors it may be better/simpler to just add things to the array as you go. When you find it time to display the errors it's a simple check to see if anything was added to the array (be checking to see if it exists).